# Consistency in Present Tense Sentences

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, present-tense

Which is correct/more appropriate?

> She has knocked over the vase before I can stop her.

OR

> She knocks over the vase before I can stop her.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: They're both fine; which would be better (and this is more of a style issue rather than a grammar issue) depends on the context.

Comment: @Peter Shor   Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: It's unclear why you are using present tense.

Comment: @HotLicks Spot on.  Without an explanation of the situation being envisaged, no answer is possible.

Comment: This use of the present tense sounds like narration or inner monologue.